# Why the table does not make changes after the query is executed

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Why the table does not make changes after the query is executed.  There is no psycopg2 information, the price did not change after the query was made in the table or when the IDLE/console was displayed

```
def connect_to_database(self):
        try:
            self.conn = psycopg2.connect(**self.db_params)
            print("Connected to database.")
            revert to connector.
        except (exception, psycopg2.Error) as an error:
            print(f"Error connecting to PostgreSQL: {error}")
            not return

    def foo(self):
        condition = self.query_text_field.get("1.0", "end-1c")

        query = f"""
                UPDATE PRODUCTS
                Installation price = price* 0.9
                {condition}; # condition = 'WHERE "group" = "Bakery"'
                SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS
            """
        self.cursor.execute(query)
        self.conn.commit()

        result = self.cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: The query execution returns the number of "affected rows". Is it zero or more than zero?

Comment: It might be because you are putting the column name 'group' inside quotation marks. So "group" is never equal to "Bakery". Your condition should not have the column name in quotation marks but in brackets like [group] probably.

Comment: @INN_ I. I found a solution, I used single quotation marks instead of double quotation marks in the query to specify the column name

Comment: No you didn't find the solution. The solution is to **not** use `f` strings and the attendant SQL injection risk, but instead use the `psycopg2` [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) module to do dynamic SQL the safe way. Among other things it does the proper quoting for you.